# Linear Algebra Vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Lets say you have $\vec{a}$(2,1) and $\vec{b}$(0,3)

Are these lines the same?

$ L_1 = \{\vec{b} + t_1 (\vec{b}-\vec{a}) \mid t_1 \in\mathbb{R} \}$

$ L_2 = \{\vec{a} + t_2 (\vec{b}-\vec{a}) \mid t_2 \in\mathbb{R} \}$

Comment: What is the definition of a line? That is helpful here. What can't you do?

Comment: How can I explain this.. I want to know if the span of these 2 L's in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is the same.

Comment: @ZafarS "span of a line"?

Comment: @ZafarS **hint** Can one be rearranged to be exactly like the other?

Comment: $2$ points are sufficient to determine a line. You've got two points. If both points satisfy both lines, it means the lines are same as there is a **unique** line passing through two distinct points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{array}{lcl}
L_2 & = &\{ a + t_2(b-a) & \mid t_2 \in\mathbb{R} \} \\
    & = &\{ (b-b)+ a + t_2(b-a)&\mid t_2 \in\mathbb{R} \} \\
    & = &\{b + (t_2-1)(b-a)&\mid t_2 \in\mathbb{R}\} \\
    & = &\{b + t'(b-a)& \mid t' \in \mathbb{R}\} \\
    & = &L_1
\end{array}$$